# What is feedthrough in vlsi standard standard cell library gates?

Tags: cmos, vlsi

I come across with the term feedthrough in standard library cells, but i did not understand its function.

Comment: Can you provide a specific example? It's usually a signal that does not go through any gates in the cell.

Comment: @awjlogan i saw it in all digital gates in provided cell library for one of the school project done in Magic. It does go through the  cells like nor cell, and cell. However, we did not use this signal, and connected it to nothing in logic level :) so i am curious about its function.

Comment: Yeah, just looked at the docs and that what it is - it's signals that are not operated on inside the cell. An example could be Vdd which is the same in/out. @justavlsistudent

Answer (score 1):

I find out myself that the answer to this question is sometimes wiring gates may be troublesome because of low space. Feedthrough helps here to wire a way out through the gate bypassing it, and connecting to nothing in the gate.